# what do the lockflags do in direct3d

Tags: video, rendering, direct3d

i'm using direct3d to render yuv video data.  the basic process is:

create a yv12 surface using CreateOffscreenPlain
lockrectangle on this surface to get the data pointer, copy yuv data to it.
stretchrectangle from this surface to the backbuffer
call present to display the back buffer.

on the LockRectangle call there's a LockFlags parameter and we have been using LockFlags.Discard which sounds like it means that we'll overwrite the whole buffer.

This seems to cause some issues (exceptions on present) on some intel onboard graphics devices, whereas if i change the LockFlags to LockFlags.None, the problem seems to go away.  have i created a race condition by doing this?

i think i probably need to understand the necessity of the lock here.  the display is in 32 bit rgb so i would guess that the yuv to rgb conversion is done on the stretchrectangle call.  is this process suppose to be synchronous or asynchronous?  i think i've read that present is asynchronous but that doesn't matter to me since that's an operation on the backbuffer which i don't touch directly.

apologize if the questions don't make sense, i don't think i've got a very good handle on this thus far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm asuming your using D3D9?  Either way its the same on all APIs.

When using "D3DLOCK_DISCARD" you should always rewrite all the data in the buffer.  It sounds like you may not be?

If your intension is to rewrite all the data in the buffer you do want to be using "Discard" for performance reasons.  If your only writing a part of the data you can use 'none'.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb147263(v=vs.85).aspx
"If the graphics processor is still using the buffer when lock is called with D3DLOCK_DISCARD, a pointer to a new region of memory is returned instead of the old buffer data."

Comment: Yes I am on D3D9.  I am rewriting the entire buffer and it is true that DSDLOCK_DISCARD seems to have slightly better performance on most systems, but i can't figure out why this flag would cause exceptions on some systems with intel onboard graphics.  I'm having to use LockFlags.None for compatibility and living with the hit to performance, plus i hate having fixes in there that i don't fully understand.

Comment: If you don't need Windows XP support you could move to D3D11... Much cleaner API and runs on Windows vista to windows 8.  D3D11 supports direct3d9 video cards.